# Facebook Sharer not showing image thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I have followed an example of Facebook share by using URL and parameters

**Original (working)**

Fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/dYfwK/

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s= 100&amp;p[title]=Title here&amp;p[url]=http://example.com&amp;p[images][0]=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Kaasmarkt2_close.jpg&amp;p[summary]=I love cheese" target="_blank">Test</a>
```

**Modified (image not appearing)**

Fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/dYfwK/6/

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s= 100&amp;p[title]=Title here&amp;p[url]=http://example.com&amp;p[images]
    [0]=http://www.ucmas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/rm.jpg&amp;p[summary]=I love cheese" target="_blank">Test</a>
```

I've been facing this issue for sometime, eventually I believe this issue is due to the image. Is it the size or something else that caused this ?

Comment: That second images takes 12 seconds to load in my browser – so maybe that’s the reason (for good user experience, FB wants things to load _fast_). But anyway, the share dialog will only accept the URL of the content to share and no additional parameters any more (it’ll get that info from the URLs Open Graph meta tags instead) from Oct. 2013 on, https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#oct_2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I do this it works:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Title+here&p[url]=http://example.com&p[summary]=I+love+cheese&p[images][0]=http://www.ucmas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/rm.jpg" target="_blank">Test</a>
```

What you need to do is remove `&amp;` from the url and replace it with real &. I then url encoded everything that wasnt a link. this just means replace spaces with `+`. I also put image at the end of the url. Not sure why but that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#deprecated-params

As per latest updates below url works.Picture image has been replaced with u param for sharing media url,and link for redirect url.

[https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=${img}&link=${window.location.href}](https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=$%7Bimg%7D&link=$%7Bwindow.location.href%7D)