# Facebook sharer.php working unexpeted or not properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am using facebook sharer.php for share posts with images. But when i click on share button facebook sharer.php dialog showing with image and text that i have set. see image below:

[image]

After i click on share button. Post will be show on my facebook timeline. But there is no image with post. I think it is bug. below is my code

`<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s= 100&p[title]=Title here&p[url]=http://example.com&p[images]
    [0]=http://www.ucmas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/rm.jpg&p[summary]=I love cheese" target="_blank">Share post</a>`

You can test thing in this post fiddle also.

[Facebook Sharer not showing image thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920726/facebook-sharer-not-showing-image-thumbnail)

Any help?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running your site through the Facebook debugger? Not only will it show you what's wrong in 99% of cases, but it will also, every single time, clear facebook's cache of your page. Go here:

[enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Enter your url, and see if there are any errors. My guess is that Facebook cached the fact that it couldn't find any image of yours, so simply doing that is likely to solve your problem. If not, your image is probably not publicly accessible.

Comment: Here is my image publicly available     http://www.jobmre.com:3000/system/news_vimgs/13/original/JobMRE_Samir_Addahre.png

Comment: Here is my job url  http://jobmre.com:3000/news/13. That not showing above image on facebook debug.

Comment: Neither of those URLs is available for me right now.

Comment: Yep. I can't access those images. I suggest you first try it with an image you can access directly from your browser (and before you post them here, check them yourself).
Your problem is that Facebook can't access your images to cache them. That's it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use faceboot meta tags.

```
`<meta property="og:image" content="http://davidwalsh.name/wp-content/themes/klass/img/facebooklogo.png"/>`

`<meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Open Graph META Tags"/>`
```

REF: 
http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Comment: how it will work and how i can use meta tags just like sharer php pop up.

Comment: You'll basically add those meta tags in your `<head>`tag. Facebook fetch the contest from shared URL parse the meta tags and will show the image, title, or page description from those tags.